# How to view audit requests generated by Collaborator Everywhere extension in BurpSuite?

Tags: burp

I would like to inspect those requests sent by Collaborator Everywhere extension to see whether it works or not. I concern this issue since I cannot get any access log in my Apache2 server used to test (forensic_log mod is enable).

Answer (score 0):

This extension modifies in-scope requests coming to proxy on-the-fly.So we can actually se the extension's request in Logger tab.